# the Expression Language (EL) showing error in if condition in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Im sending data from login.java to stu.jsp

below is the login.java code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
       {
           boolean message = true;
           request.setAttribute("message", message); // This will be available as ${message}
           request.getRequestDispatcher("stu.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }
```

[this is the stu.jsp code (showing error)]
Please click on the image to view the code with error

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSOWw.png)

below is just the same code as above in the image
which is showing an error in the if condition in EL

```
<% if ( ${message} ) { %>
         <p> Today is weekend</p>
      <% } else { %>
         <p> Today is not weekend</p>
      <% } %>
```

Below is the complete error message when i run the server

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [89] in the jsp file: [/stu.jsp]
Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement
86:         
87:           
88:  
89:       <% if ( ${message} ) { %>
90:          <p> Today is weekend</p>
91:       <% } else { %>
92:          <p> Today is not weekend</p>


An error occurred at line: [89] in the jsp file: [/stu.jsp]
$ cannot be resolved to a variable
86:         
87:           
88:  
89:       <% if ( ${message} ) { %>
90:          <p> Today is weekend</p>
91:       <% } else { %>
92:          <p> Today is not weekend</p>


An error occurred at line: [89] in the jsp file: [/stu.jsp]
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
86:         
87:           
88:  
89:       <% if ( ${message} ) { %>
90:          <p> Today is weekend</p>
91:       <% } else { %>
92:          <p> Today is not weekend</p>


An error occurred at line: [91] in the jsp file: [/stu.jsp]
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
88:  
89:       <% if ( ${message} ) { %>
90:          <p> Today is weekend</p>
91:       <% } else { %>
92:          <p> Today is not weekend</p>
93:       <% } %>
94:     


An error occurred at line: [647] in the generated java file: [D:\Browser Downloads\setup -2\eclipse\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-9.0.54\work\Catalina\localhost\PPP\org\apache\jsp\stu_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:487)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    pack.login.doPost(login.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Please help me in resolving this issue
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add the actual error message from the JSP compiler.

Comment: error message added, you can click on the image link to view the error mesage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` is an attribute in JSP and everything inside `<%... %>` is java code.

Inside Java code, you cannot use `${}` as you can only use Java syntax.

Knowing this, you have two possibilities:

Either access `message` using `request.getAttribute()` inside `<% %>`:

```
<% if ((Boolean)request.getAttribute("message")) { %>
         <p> Today is weekend</p>
      <% } else { %>
         <p> Today is not weekend</p>
      <% } %>
```

Or you could use `c:if`:

```
<c:if test="${message}">
    <p> Today is weekend</p> 
</c:if>
<c:if test="${! message}">
    <p> Today is not weekend</p> 
</c:if>
```

Comment: for the 1st possibility im getting the below error 

Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [89] in the jsp file: [/stu.jsp]
message cannot be resolved to a variable
86:         
87:           
88:  
89: <% if (message) { %>
90:          <p> Today is weekend</p>
91:       <% } else { %>
92:          <p> Today is not weekend</p>

Comment: for the 2nd possibility both the if conditions are returning true

Comment: My fault. I edited it.

Comment: 1st one is working thank you so much